# regular expression numbers followed by any characters

Tags: regex

I have want to match a string which starts with number, followed by any characters and ends with .html;

I have tried the following:

```
/([0-9]*[^\.html]*.html)/g
```

But [Regexr](http://regexr.com/3ac5u) for an example like "21212dfsd.htmlfdf.html" says 2 matches?! Why is that?

Thanks

Comment: It says "1 match" to me.

Comment: `[^\.html]` does not do what you want. There's also an unescaped dot `.` before `html`.

Comment: Change the * to a plus after the numbers because you are requiring a number.

Comment: on top right it says 2 matches but substitition is giving me just one; for my exampel like 21212dfsd.htmlfdf.html it should be just one match which is 21212dfsd.html , right?

Comment: /([0-9]*[^\.html]*.html)/g

says 0 or more numbers

/([0-9]+[^\.html]*.html)/g

says 1 or more numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get two matches because of the `*` quantifier following the character class. `*` means match the preceding token "zero or more" times. Use `+` instead, meaning "one or more".

You can't place whole words inside of a character class as well. A character class matches any one character from a set of characters and the dot `.` needs to be escaped (*it's a character* of **special** *meaning*).

You can use the below regular expression:

```
/\d+.*?\.html/g
```

Comment: Thanks so much for nice explanation; so when I use your regular expression , I'm getting one match, but why $1 in substitution for `/(\d+.*?\.html)/g` is returnung whole string? Thanks again

Comment: It returns the whole string because your placing the match right back into place.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand! even without having parenthesis `/\d+.*?\.html/g`, although there is 1 match, $1 in substitution returns `$1fdf.html`, maybe I don't understand the logic of substitution here!

Comment: I would recommend reading up on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewy2t5e0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx